# Sencha touch List

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I'm new in sencha touch. I run into some strange behavior. Shortly I want to make one window with toolbar and list below.

**Main launch code**:

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    enabled: true
});

Ext.application({
    name: 'xxx',

    controllers: ['Main'],
    views: ['Home', 'Header', 'Footer', 'list.MainMenu'],
    stores: ['MainMenu'],
    models: ['MenuItem'],


    launch: function() {
        Ext.create('xxx.view.Viewport');
    }
});
```

**Viewport view**:

```
Ext.define('xxx.view.Viewport', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',

    config: {
        fullscreen: true,

        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'headerpanel',
            },{
                xtype: 'MainMenu'
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

**Header view**:

```
Ext.define('xxx.view.Header', {
    extend: Ext.Panel,
    xtype: 'headerpanel',

    config: {               
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'titlebar',
                docked: 'top',
                title: '<img src="lib/resources/images/x.png" />',  

                items: [
                    {
                        text: 'One',
                        align: 'left'
                    },{
                        text: 'Two',
                        align: 'right'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

**Meniu view**:

```
Ext.define('xxx.view.list.MainMenu', {
    extend: 'Ext.List',
    xtype: 'MainMenu',

    requires: ['xxx.store.MainMenu'],

    config: {
        itemTpl: '{title}',
        store: 'MainMenu'       
    }
});
```

**Menu store**:

```
Ext.define('xxx.store.MainMenu', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

    config: {
        model: 'xxx.model.MenuItem',
        data: [
            {icon: 'a', title: 'A'},
            {icon: 'b', title: 'B'},
        ]
    }
});
```

**Menu model**:

```
Ext.define('xxx.model.MenuItem', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',   

    config: {
        fields: ['icon', 'title']
    }
});
```

The result of this piece code is **just toolbar without any list**.

[image]

I set layout to *'fit'* value the result is opposite: only list I can see.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to set a layout to your Viewport view. Without a layout, container don't know how to display inner items.

Try the following :

```
Ext.define('xxx.view.Viewport', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',

    config: {
        fullscreen: true,
        layout:'fit',
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'titlebar',
                docked: 'top',
                title: '<img src="lib/resources/images/x.png" />',  

                items: [{
                    text: 'One',
                    align: 'left'
                },{
                    text: 'Two',
                    align: 'right'
                }]
            },{
                xtype: 'list',
                itemTpl: '{title}',
                store: 'MainMenu' 
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

You can find more about layout [here](http://www.sencha.com/learn/intro-to-layouts-in-sencha-touch-2)

Comment: Any particular reason you're using three different views (files) instead of just one ? Updated my answer

Comment: I just wanted to keep separate any view from header panel(view) which is always top docked in the viewport. Now your soliutions is working as i expected. Any good navigations patterns you could offer to read?

Comment: For navigation, use the Sencha Component called Ext.navigation.View. http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.navigation.View